# Como somar 2 objetos e retornar número, em Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, objetos, programação-funcional

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
class num(int):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
```

Gostaria que funciona-se da seguinte forma:

```
A = num(2)
B = num(3)
A + B = 5
```

Isso faz parte de um projeto pessoal bem mais complexo. Já pesquisei as funções BuiltIn, até os **add** e **str** e nada. Por favor, me ajudem!

Comment: E por que o `__add__` não satisfaz sua necessidade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode implementar o método [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) na sua classe:

```
class num(int):
     def __init__(self, n):
         self.n = n
     def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, num):
            return self.n + other.n
        else:
            return self.n + other

a = num(1)
b = num(2)
print(a + b) # 3
print(3 + a) # 4
print(a + 4) # 5
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ainda existem pessoas boas neste mundo! hahaha

Comment: Seria melhor ainda retornar uma nova instância de `num` com o atributo `n` igual à soma dos valores, e não apenas a soma dos valores em si.